# Accessing MVC ViewBag array from Javascript file with jQuery.Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've tried multiple solutions from Stack Overflow but still having issues access a MVC ViewBag from a function within a Javascript file.

In View:

```
    <input type="text" id="myHiddenVar" />

    <script>
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Files));
        $( "#myHiddenVar" ).data( array );
        console.log($("#myHiddenVar").data());
        }
    </script>
```

This works as I expect and sends what I expect/need to the console. 
Object {0: file1", 1: "file2", 2: "file3"}

In jsHelper.js file:

```
        function getFiles() {
            var test = $("#myHiddenVar").data();
            console.log(test);
            return test;
        }
```

This just sends Object {} to the console when the function is called (from another function in jsHelper.js).

Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling getFiles() after set the data?

Comment: Based on various logging I am fairly certain. The getFiles function is called by another function when a drop down selector fires a onSelect event. It makes me think there is some kind of public/private shenanigans going on but I don't know where.

Comment: I suggest you set val() instead of data() for testing `$( "#myHiddenVar" ).val(JSON.stringify(array));` and read it in getFiles `$("#myHiddenVar").val();` and let's see if it works in this way? may be another part of the code is clearing the data()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still no luck. I really don't want to mark my own suggestion as Answered but Javascript variables in the View page can be accessed from a javascript file. 

In View:
`function pullFiles() { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Files)); } var availFiles = pullFiles();`

In jsHelper.js file: 
`function getFiles() { var test = availFiles; }`

This is working for what I need, the real solution would to be a AJAX call directly to the controller I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var array2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Files));
var array = JSON.parse(array2);
```